# Office 365 without Azure AD

Tags: azure, outlook

I want to create an application to get contacts from my Office 365 with v2 app model preview (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#v2appmodelpreview).

But I have a problem with access to http://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts. After authorization I have the access token and the refresh token. Then I can get contacts information.

But after an hour my access token is invalid. Using refresh token I get a new access token. But when I try to access my contacts I received error "access token is invalid".

I try to do the same with Azure AD - everything is good. Can anybody help me?